# Render page with specific id from functions.php

Tags: functions, templates

How can I render a page from functions.php with a specific page `id`?

I tried something like this:

```php
$template = locate_template('page.php');
if ($template) {
    set_query_var('page', get_post_meta( 200 ) );

    return load_template($template);
}
```

Comment: Render the entire page, including header and footer?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes, exactly the same as page with id 200 would be rendered by default.